# Operator norm of positive operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm studying Reed and Simon's "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics" Vol. 1 (http://www.math.bme.hu/~balint/oktatas/fun/notes/Reed_Simon_Vol1.pdf).
In the proof of the square root lemma (p.196) they use the equation

$\|I-A\|=\sup\limits_{|\varphi|=1}|((I-A)\varphi,\varphi)|,$

where $A$ is a bounded positive operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $I$ is the identity operator in $\mathcal{H}$. 
I understand that for any bounded operator $T$, the Cauchy-Schwarz imequality implies that

$\|T\|\geq\sup\limits_{|\varphi|=1}|(T\varphi,\varphi)|$.

But I am not able to prove the other inequality. Under what hypothesis is it true?

Comment: I think so, as positive implies self-adjoint.

Comment: So for bounded self adjoint opeartors in Hilbert space you have $||A||=\sup_{||x||=1}|\langle Ax,x\rangle|$

Comment: @uniquesolution is that a fact?  Do you happen to know the proof? Or, do you have a reference?

Comment: Yes, it is a standard fact.  See here: lemma 8.26. https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch8.pdf

Comment: @uniquesolution excellent!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That holds in most general case for even unbounded normal operators: $\|N\|=\|\sigma(N)\|$, $\langle\sigma(N)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(N)}$. Reference: [Norm](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/975448/79762), [Numerical Range](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084146/79762)

Comment: @BrunoSuzuki: You might have a look on: [Boundary](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355116/spectrum-boundary)

Comment: Can you please explain why $(I - A)$ is self-adjoint? I am getting that it is self-adjoit iff $A$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that $T := (I - A)$ is self-adjoint. Let $M := \sup_{\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm x = 1} \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\abs{\<Tx,x>}$, we will show that $\norm T \le M$. Let $x,y \in H$, then
\begin{align*} 
  \<T(x+y),x+y> - \<T(x-y),x-y> &= 2\<Tx,y> + 2\<Ty,x>\\
                                &= 2\<Tx,y> + 2\<x,Tx>\\
                                &= 4\Re\<Tx,y>
\end{align*}
Hence, due to the parallelogram identity,
\begin{align*}
  4\Re\<Tx,y> &\le M\norm{x+y}^2 + M\norm{x-y}^2\\
         &= 2M\bigl(\norm x^2 +\norm y^2 \bigr)
\end{align*}
Hence, we have
$$ \Re \<Tx, y> \le M, \qquad \norm x, \norm y \le 1 $$
Now, given $y$ choose $\lambda \in \mathbf C$ with $\abs \lambda = 1$ such that $\Re \<Tx,\lambda y> = \abs{\<Tx, y>}$, then $\abs{\<Tx,y>} \le M$, hence
$$ \norm T = \sup_{\norm x, \norm y \le 1}\abs{\<Tx,y>} \le M. $$

Comment: Can you please explain why $(I - A)$ is self-adjoint? I am getting that it is self-adjoit iff $A$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: And $A $ is positive, hence self-adjoint.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that A is positive. Thank you

Comment: Could you please explain to me why \begin{aligned}
4 \Re\langle T x, y\rangle & \leq M\|x+y\|^2+M\|x-y\|^2 \\
& =2 M\left(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\right)
\end{aligned}

Comment: @TungNguyen Since martini has not been active here for 2 years, I took the liberty of correcting some mistypings. The "Hence" before the inequality is now clear.

Comment: @AnneBauval The only thing I don't understand is the inequality in the formulation. Why do we have "less than $M\Vert x+y\Vert^2$".

Comment: @TungNguyen It was shown just before that
$4\Re\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle T(x+y),x+y\rangle- \langle T(x-y),x-y\rangle$. Now, by definition of $M$, $|\<T(z),z>|\le M\|z\|^2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval But I thought it was only for $z$ such that $\Vert z\Vert  =1$?

Comment: For any $z\ne0$, let $x:=z/\|z\|$. Then, $\langle T(z),z\rangle=\|z\|^2\langle T(x),x\rangle$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you a lot. I have understood everything perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Denote numerical range:
$$\mathcal{W}(A):=\{\langle A\hat\varphi,\hat\varphi\rangle:\|\hat\varphi\|=1\}$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\|\mathcal{W}(A)\|\leq\|A\|1\cdot1=\|A\|$$

For bounded operators:
$$A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\sigma(A)\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}$$

For normal operators:*
$$N^*N=NN^*:\quad\|N\|=\|\sigma(N)\|$$

> All together gives:
>   $$\|N\|=\|\sigma(N)\|\leq\|\mathcal{W}(N)\|\leq\|N\|$$
>   Concluding equality.

**Hint: Neumann-Series*